# Writing script for Autohotkey for invoking 'Shift+F5' keystrokes

Tags: autohotkey

I have to run few applications like browser and ticketing tool. But, I need to continuously press shift+F5 keystrokes for reloading the pages of my browser and ticketing tool.

Can I use any script through autohotkey for invoking 'Shift+F5' keys repeatedly for every 20 seconds regular interval?

Can anybody please help me with writing the script for autohotkey for invoking 'Shift+F5' keystrokes?

Comment: Could you provide some feedback? Was the proposed solution helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to be able to turn this feature on/off

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

#F5:: ; [Win]+[F5] to start timer
SetTimer, RefreshPage, 20000
TrayTip, Refresh, Started, 1
ToolTip, Refresh Active
Return

+#F5:: ; [Shift]+[Win]+[F5] to stop timer
SetTimer, RefreshPage, Off
TrayTip, Refresh, Stopped, 1
ToolTip
Return

RefreshPage:
    Send, +{F5}
Return
```